# Shiny searchInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a "shinyWidget :: searchInput" designed with a grid that would allow entering only 9 digits in the field?
https://pasteboard.co/J3mduIS.png

Comment: This is called a pincode input. There are some Jquery plugins: https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Pin%20Code/

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm going to try this !

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent would you have an example of an application that implements this type of input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shiny implementation of `bootstrap-pincode-input`.

Download the files **bootstrap-pincode-input.js** and **bootstrap-pincode-input.css** [from here](https://github.com/fkranenburg/bootstrap-pincode-input). Put them in the **www** subfolder of the folder containing the shiny app.

Also add the JS file below to the **www** subfolder, call it **pincodeBinding.js**.

```js
var pincodeBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

$.extend(pincodeBinding, {
  find: function (scope) {
    return $(scope).find(".pincode");
  },
  getValue: function (el) {
    return $(el).val();
  },
  setValue: function(el, value) {
    $(el).val(value);
  },
  subscribe: function (el, callback) {
    $(el).on("change.pincodeBinding", function (e) {
      callback();
    });
  },
  unsubscribe: function (el) {
    $(el).off(".pincodeBinding");
  },
  initialize: function(el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.pincodeInput({
      inputs: $el.data("ndigits"),
      hidedigits: $el.data("hide"),
      complete: function(value, e, errorElement){
        Shiny.setInputValue($el.attr("id"), value); 
      }
    });
  }
});

Shiny.inputBindings.register(pincodeBinding);
```

Now, the shiny app:

```r
library(shiny)

pincodeInput <- function(inputId, width = "30%", height = "100px", 
                         label = NULL, ndigits = 4, hideDigits = FALSE){
  tags$div(style = sprintf("width: %s; height: %s;", width, height),
           shiny:::shinyInputLabel(inputId, label),
           tags$input(id = inputId, class = "pincode", type = "text", 
                      `data-ndigits` = ndigits,
                      `data-hide` = ifelse(hideDigits, "true", "false")
           )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "bootstrap-pincode-input.css"),
    tags$script(src = "bootstrap-pincode-input.js"),
    tags$script(src = "pincodeBinding.js")
  ),
  br(),
  pincodeInput("pincode", label = "Enter pincode"),
  br(),
  h3("You entered:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("pincodeValue")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["pincodeValue"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["pincode"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that the pincode input only accepts digits, not alphabetical characters. I don't know whether this is what you want?

[image]

---

## EDIT: clearable pincode input

Add this CSS file in the **www** folder, name it **pincode-input.css**:

```css
.clearable {
  padding: 1px 6px 1px 1px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.clearable span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Replace **pincodeBinding.js** with this file:

```js
var pincodeBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();

$.extend(pincodeBinding, {
  find: function (scope) {
    return $(scope).find(".pincode");
  },
  getValue: function (el) {
    return $(el).val();
  },
  setValue: function(el, value) {
    $(el).val(value);
  },
  subscribe: function (el, callback) {
    $(el).on("change.pincodeBinding", function (e) {
      callback();
    });
  },
  unsubscribe: function (el) {
    $(el).off(".pincodeBinding");
  },
  initialize: function(el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        var clearBtn = el.nextElementSibling;
        $el.pincodeInput({
      inputs: $el.data("ndigits"),
      hidedigits: $el.data("hide"),
      complete: function(value, e, errorElement){
        Shiny.setInputValue($el.attr("id"), value); 
      }, 
      change: function(){
        clearBtn.style.visibility = ($el.val().length) ? "visible" : "hidden";
      }
    });
    clearBtn.onclick = function() {
      this.style.visibility = "hidden";
      $el.pincodeInput().data("plugin_pincodeInput").clear();
      Shiny.setInputValue($el.attr("id"), "");
    };
  }
});

Shiny.inputBindings.register(pincodeBinding);
```

The app:

```r
library(shiny)

pincodeInput <- function(inputId, width = "30%", height = "100px", 
                         label = NULL, ndigits = 4, hideDigits = FALSE){
  tags$div(style = sprintf("width: %s; height: %s;", width, height),
           shiny:::shinyInputLabel(inputId, label),
           tags$span(
             class = "clearable",
             tags$input(id = inputId, class = "pincode", type = "text", 
                        `data-ndigits` = ndigits,
                        `data-hide` = ifelse(hideDigits, "true", "false")
             ),
             tags$span(title = "Clear", HTML("&times;"))
           )
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "bootstrap-pincode-input.css"),
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "pincode-input.css"),
    tags$script(src = "bootstrap-pincode-input.js"),
    tags$script(src = "pincodeBinding.js") 
  ),
  br(),
  pincodeInput("pincode", label = "Enter pincode"),
  br(),
  h3("You entered:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("pincodeValue")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output[["pincodeValue"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["pincode"]]
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I know I'm asking a lot, but how would you get the 'clear' function added?

Comment: Again it works like a charm ! Except for version 3.3 of R (I can't install a newer version on my work server). Many thanks !